# Convert a string containing a number in scientific notation to a normal string in PHP

Tags: php, scientific-notation

[image]

I need help converting a string that contains a number in scientific notation to a normal string.
Example strings: "9.1892E+11" to "918919850755"

Comment: As far as I understand: 9.1892E+11 = `918920000000`

Comment: I used some predefined functions like : number_format, dechex etc. but not getting exact value.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thanks for quick response but number is 918919850755. Scientific string generated from csv cell.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

PHP should understand the scientific notation. 
By substracting or adding 0 or something, it will change to a normal notation.

By doing this you might lose precision. 
You can cast the string to a float to prevent this.

```
$number = (float)$number;
```

Comment: Not getting exact number by subtracting 0. 
"918920000000"

Comment: Did you notice the update of my answer about casting?

Comment: Yes I tried it but getting same result "918920000000".

Comment: Please see the attached screenshot.

Comment: The value displayes in the cell is excels visual representation of the value in the bar (and the cells actual value), but they're not the same.

Comment: I didn't get any thing from you my friend.

Comment: I just need "918919850755" in the output.